# How to change font and font size of 1 element in navbar without affecting other elements

Tags: html, css, navbar

Hi I’m pretty new to html and css so I was wondering how to achieve a navbar like this basically:

[basic navbar with logo in Lobster font and everything else in Arial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/794sK.jpg)

code:

```
<style>
    html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Lobster;
  }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    .navbar a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
    }
}
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: rgb(163, 163, 163) 1px solid;

}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: rgb(94, 92, 92);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: rgb(131, 130, 130);
}

.navbar a.active {
 font: Lobster;
 font-size: 35px;
 color: #990000;
}
.navbar-right {
  float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="home.html">SalEats!</a>
  <div class="navbar-right">
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a href="login.html">Login/Sign Up</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My main issue is when I change the size of the logo and make it lobster font, it changes the font for the other elements to lobster and makes them unaligned. 
Would it be easier to just use an image for the logo? Please let me know, thank you!

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni just added it

Answer (score 0):

The exact CSS would depend on your HTML. CSS styles on an HTML attribute are inherited by all its children (with some caveats). So just put the style for your logo font the the element that is the immediate parent of the text, like an `h1` element.

If your whole header just text inside one element, then add a child element to contain the logo text. For example:

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <h1 class="logo-text">My Title</h1>
  <div>Other stuff in the navbar</div>
</div>
```

```css
.navbar {
  /* ... navbar style */
}

.logo-text {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: ... (your font)
}
```

---

**Edit:** I'm guessing that maybe you are using a semi-automatic service like Squarespace or Wordpress so you are not actually writing the HTML, just the CSS. If this is the case, then go to your website bring up your browser's developer tools (F12 on most browsers). Use the "Pick an element" tool to select your header and drill down through the HTML to find your logo. Hopefully there will be a unique element that is the direct parent of your header text. Make a note of what class/id that element has so you can write your CSS. If that is not the case (like if all the elements of the navbar have the same class) then look into [CSS pseudoclasses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size), especially `:first-child`.